# What difference between require 'a' and require 'a.rb'?

Tags: ruby

I'm reading the source code of a Ruby project. If there is a file named a.rb. And I see somebody requires it as:

```
require 'a'
```

But somebody does:

```
require 'a.rb'
```

Are these same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`require 'a.rb'` only search for `a.rb`, while `require 'a'` also search for `a.rb`, `a.so`,  ...

---

According to [`Kernel#require` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require):

> If the filename has the extension “.rb”, it is loaded as a source
>   file; if the extension is “.so”, “.o”, or “.dll”, or the default
>   shared library extension on the current platform, Ruby loads the
>   shared library as a Ruby extension. Otherwise, Ruby tries adding
>   “.rb”, “.so”, and so on to the name until found. If the file named
>   cannot be found, a LoadError will be raised.